# How to instance a roof tiles?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Imagine that I have a mesh, that represents a quite complicated roof, consists of planar faces:

[image]

Is it possible to instance a roof tiles like this using geometry nodes?

[image]

Here is the setup that I have now:

[image]

But I want to get the solution, which is:

- Adds tiles even if it covers by another roof

[image]

- Tiles has even distribution even if angle of the roof changes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i just have an idea, but i think i cannot realize it, but maybe you can :) if your roof faces are all rectangular, you could replace each face with a grid of the same size, rotation and position and calculate based on the width and length the needed vertices x and vertices y. On that you can than instance on points.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Why are you not using the Tissue Addon? It works great for creating complex roofs. https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue

Comment: @ChristophWerner I'm working on building generator, it is a part of it.

Comment: @Chris the problem is that they are not rectangular. They are planar, but not rectangular

Comment: OK. Understand. Unfortunately I haven't enough time to get into this.

Answer (score 0):

you can you the *island index* multiplied by the *bounding box* max to offset the mesh islands in order to isolate them, then do the operation, and them offset them back to their original position

you might also want to make more than one grid, or make the  grid dependent on the bounding box.