# Any method to have roof tiles distribute evenly on both uniform and non uniform faces?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Any method to have roof tiles distribute evenly on both uniform and non uniform faces?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the method that I have used so far.

[image]

[image]

It makes an even grid of points that's raycasted down on the roof. Because it is a grid, tiles distributes evenly, on any surface.

[image]

Even on N-gons:

[image]

This solves your issue, but unfortunately it has some disadvantages, that I have described here:

[How to instance a roof tiles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276585/how-to-instance-a-roof-tiles)

Comment: Nice method! I believe that your method is computationally more efficient than the method from Blender Guru: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OsgS2JpM8k